# What tense did use in when-clause?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

A teachbook says that 'be going to' is the substitute for modal verb 'will'. Example:

> When I was going to school, I was preoccupied with good grades.

What tense did use the first clause, and why? Because 'will' produces future tense, but I saw past continuous.

Comment: "**is** going to" and "will" are used to form the future tense , but "**was** going to" is used to form the past tense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When I was going to school* is indeed the past continuous; it is not the same use of *be going to.*

As a substitute for *will*, you could say "When I get home from work, I'm going to start preparing my evening meal."  "Tomorrow I'm going to play football."